# Plotly Not Found

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

Howdy I am a beginner at python and have just begun to work with plotly but have been having a few problems with the module because of the "ModuleNotFoundError" error message, here's the code so you can see it:

```
import json

from plotly.graph_objs import Scattergeo, Layout
from plotly import offline

# Explore the structure of the data
filename = "C:/Users/balm2/OneDrive/Documentos/Programming/Python/Python VS/COsas raras/Chapter 16/eq_data_1_day_m1.json"
with open(filename) as f:
    all_eq_data = json.load(f)

all_eq_dicts = all_eq_data["features"]

mags, lons, lats = [], [], []
for eq_dict in all_eq_dicts:
    mag = eq_dict["properties"]["mag"]
    lon = eq_dict["geometry"]["coordinates"][0]
    lat = eq_dict["geometry"]["coordinates"][1]
    mags.append(mag)
    lons.append(lon)
    lats.append(lat)

print(mags[:10])
print(lons[:5])
print(lats[:5])

# Map the earthquakes
data = [Scattergeo(lon=lons, lat=lats)]
my_layout = Layout(title="Global Earthquakes")

fig = {"data": data, "layout": my_layout}
offline.plot(fig, filename="global_earthquakes.html")
```

And here's the error message:

```
File "C:\Users\balm2\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\_scattergeo.py", line 2248, in __init__
    self["lat"] = _v
  File "C:\Users\balm2\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 4838, in __setitem__
    validator = self._get_validator(prop)
  File "C:\Users\balm2\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 4320, in _get_validator
    return ValidatorCache.get_validator(self._path_str, prop)
  File "C:\Users\balm2\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\plotly\validator_cache.py", line 29, in get_validator
    importlib.import_module("plotly.validators." + parent_path),
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module 
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.validators.scattergeo'
```

So I've tried dealing with OneDrive since I thought it was a syncing error but haven't been lucky there, therefore I've tried uninstalling and installing once again the module but haven't been lucky once again, is there anything I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip install plotly`

I see you are on Windows so you will need to find `pip` if you havent added it to the PATH variable.
It is generally in:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3.x(version)\Scripts\pip
```

so you would run:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3.x(version)\Scripts\pip install plotly
```

Edit: replace UserName and 3.x(version) of course
Edit2: run this commands in Powershell / cmd :)